# How to write a jQuery function with a callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have the following function:

```
function loadProjects(pID) {

    $.ajax({
        url: myURL,
        success: function (dataJS) {XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}
    });
}
```

I call this function like so loadProjects(1);

Issue is I want to be able to define a callBack function after success, and I'd like to include it when I do loadProjects(1, callback:{whatever js is included here gets called back after success})

How can I have a function accept a callback?
How can I pass a callback to that function?

Thanks

Comment: Everyone thank you. But I want callback to be anything I want. I don't want the callback to be static?

Comment: Thanks again but all these are static callbacks, it doesn't allow me to define things like callbackfunc(22)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
function loadProjects(pID, callbackFunction)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: myURL,
        success: function (dataJS)
        {
            if(typeof callbackFunction == 'function')
            {
                callbackFunction.call(this, dataJS);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Usage:

```
loadProjects(pID, function(dataJS)
{
    // do stuff with your dataJS, bear in mind you can call the parameter any name.
});
```

Comment: +1 for correctly guessing that he wanted to pass parameters to the callback

Comment: This question deserves a -1 for poor wording.

Comment: My dad always taught me that the tricky part isn't figuring out the solution, but figuring out the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you can modify your function so that it can accept a callback.

```
function loadProjects(pID, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: myURL,
        success: function (dataJS) {
          if ($.isFunction(callback)) {
            callback.call();
          }
        }
    });
}
```

Here's how you would use it.

```
function myCoolCallback() {
  alert("I am cool");
}  

loadProjects(123, myCoolCallback);
```

Or you can use it with an anonymous function like so.

```
loadProjects(123, function() {
  alert("I am cool");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function loadProjects(pID, callback) {

    $.ajax({
        url: myURL,
        success: function (dataJS) { if (callback) { callback(); } }
    });

}
```

Invoking something like this:

```
loadProjects(111, function() { alert('hello!'); });
```

Comment: but how can I pass params to callback?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a function to another function as if it were any other object. Check this out:

```
function loadProjects(pId, callback) {

  $.ajax({
    url: myUrl,
    success: function() {
      callback.call(); // <-- invokes your callback with no args
    }

}
```

You might also read up on [the MDC documentation (function.call())](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

Answer (score -1):

```
function loadProjects(pID, callback) {
  $.ajax({
    url: myURL,
    success: function (dataJS) {
      // your initial method declaration goes here
      ...

      // just call the callback method at the end of the success method
      callback();
    }
```